# Setting button'sproperty IsEnabled based if listbox has content in it with BoolConverter in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I am trying to make a button Enabled only if a listbox has at least one item in it. I am adding listboxitems by selecting them from AutoCompleteBox list. I tried to bind isEnabled property to the listbox and use BoolConverter to validate if listbox has content.

```
<Button x:Name="DisabledButton" Click="RemoveButton_Click" Content="Disabled Button" IsEnabled="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=EntitiesListBox,Converter={StaticResource CountToBooleanConverter}}"  />
```

I am missing something. I am wondering if someone can tell me what is wrong. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Silverlight XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BoolToOppositeBoolConverter x:Key="CountToBooleanConverter" />
    <local:CountGreaterThanZeroConverter x:Key="CountGreaterThanZeroConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="150">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAutoCompleteBox, Path=SelectedItem, TargetNullValue='No item selected', StringFormat='Selected Item: {0}'}" />      
    <sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="MyAutoCompleteBox" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    <Button x:Name="AddButton" Click="AddButton_Click" Content="AddButton" />
    <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" Click="RemoveButton_Click" Content="RemoveButton" />
    <Button x:Name="DisabledButton" Click="RemoveButton_Click" Content="Disabled Button" IsEnabled="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=ListBox,Converter={StaticResource CountToBooleanConverter}}"  />
    <Button x:Name="DisabledButton2" Click="RemoveButton_Click" Content="Disabled Button"  IsEnabled="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, ElementName=ListBox, Converter={StaticResource CountGreaterThanZeroConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    string currentItemText;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Items.Add("One");
        Items.Add("Two");
        Items.Add("Three");
        Items.Add("Four");
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentItemText = MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ListBox.Items.Add(currentItemText);
        ApplyDataBinding();
    }
    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            int count = ListBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1;
            for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Remove(ListBox.SelectedItems[i]);
            }
            ApplyDataBinding();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyDataBinding()
    {
        MyAutoCompleteBox.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}

public class CountGreaterThanZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            return (int)value > 0;  
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just bind to the count of the itemssource and use an observable collection?

```
 <Button x:Name="DisabledButton" Click="RemoveButton_Click" Content="Disabled Button" IsEnabled="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, ElementName=ListBox,Converter={StaticResource CountGreaterThanZeroConverter}}"  />


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value > 0;
    }
```

And in your viewmodel

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to implement it and I have problem setting ObservableCollection in here. I updated my code above with new converter. I am wondering if you woudn't mind to check the code for error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Items = new List<string>(); => Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();              The Observable collection is a collection that sends a notification when there is a change in the collection, so ideal for data binding.

Comment: I am new to observable collection. It is a little bit confusing. I am not sure what did you mean by 'Items = new List<string>(); => Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();' I mean, I am not sure what should I change in my code in order toassign this collection.

Comment: You need to change the property named Items from IList to ObservableCollection.  Then when initialising the list you assign a new Observable collection.  Then you use the new converter and the remainder of your code stays the same.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. I highly apreciate it. I finally converted Ilist to Observable Collection. However, the intented result was not achieved. The button does not change the isEnable state based on listbox items. Perphaps, I am missing something. I updated my Question with the code that I have now. I am wondering if you can look once again. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I wrote it on my blog for you because I am working and cannot upload a sample from here.  http://strugglesofacoder.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-bind-on-itemssource-of-other.html

Comment: It is so generous. Thank you a lot! It was real helpful.